# Dynamic Height Reaching to the Bottom of Browsers using CSS

Tags: css

I have a popup window containing a table and below there is a Save button.
Sometimes it has a few data records in a table, or it has many records, some other time.

I want to set this popup window's height dynamically by setting a `max-height`.  An issue is sometimes I don't do maximum the browser, or I use different browsers, or using different monitors' resolutions.  So that sometimes with many records in the table, the popup window will show nicely in a monitor, or sometimes in another monitor, the Save button at the bottom doesn't show due to a long table.

Instead of setting `max-height`, I wonder if there are some ways to set the height dynamically AND the maximum height will reach to the bottom of the browser so that Save button will show up in case of there are long records.

Below is my CSS code.

```
max-height: 900px; 
overflow-y:auto
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-height: 100%;` as long as its container has a height of 100% of the `body`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/985zxuds/)

And if you want the buttons to show at the bottom you could use `calc()` like: `max-height: calc(100% - 60px);` with 60px representing the height of the button.

[JS Fiddle - calc()](https://jsfiddle.net/985zxuds/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much Derek! but I forgot to mention Save button has to show up in case of there are long records.  `max-height: 100%` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Did you see the second part of the answer using `max-height: calc()`?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, it works beautifully.  Thank you so much!  However, somehow I test `calc( % - px)` doesn't work in my case.  If I change `calc(px - px)`, it works.  I wonder why?